# Negating string in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

[image]

I'm working with node and mongo 5. I am trying to select the field "TOTAL DUE" with a value other than '$0.00' . I think I'm able to select for '$0.00' with:

```
{'TOTAL DUE': {$regex: /\$0\./}}
```

as in the screenshot. However trying to negate this with:

```
{'TOTAL DUE': {$not :{$regex: /\$0\./}}}
```

gives the entire data set (including when TOTAL DUE does not exist),

How can I get this working?

edit:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "6386d07324da3f53abd52449"
    },
    "RowId": 0,
    "ParcelUse": "2",
    "UseDefinition": "",
    "TotalFCV": 22400,
    "Map": 0,
    "Plat": 0,
    "lat": 32.44123,
    "long": -110.7572,
    "zip": "85712-5433",
    "totalDue": 0,
    "AMOUNT": "$0.00",
    "CERT NO  ": "",
    "FEES": "$0.00",
    "INTEREST": "$0.00",
    "INTEREST DATE": "",
    "INTERESTPERCENT": "",
    "PAY": "",
    "PENALTIES": "$0.00",
    "TAX YEAR": "",
    "TOTAL DUE": "$0.00"
  }
]
```

Comment: Can you please provide the sample json in text instead of screenshot? Your current code seems working fine in [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FBZloUu2TaT)

Comment: edited single record added

Comment: I would suggest to store numerical or currency values as **number** rather than strings.

Answer (score 1):

Matching just `/\$0\./` will miss values less than $1.

If the zero due string will always be `"$0.00"`, you can use an inequality match like:

```
"TOTAL DUE": {$ne: "$0.00"}
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cmyrw2kAm7w)

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that what worked in my case was:

```
{$and: [{'TOTAL DUE': {$exists: true}},{"TOTAL DUE": {$ne: "$0.00"}}]}
```

The problem must be that not all over the documents had the 'TOTAL DUE' field. I didn't know that this would be a problem.